# Is it possible to curl across docker network via docker-compose between 2 docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have 2 application run with a different network and it uses separate docker-compose.yaml. So I trying to call an request from app A to app B, but it not works.

```
docker exec -it app_a_running curl http://localhost:8012/user/1
```

So I got an error

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8012
```

docker-compose-app-a.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: go/
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8011:8011
    volumes:
    - ../src/app:/go/src/app
    working_dir: /go/src/app
    container_name: app-a
    command: sleep 72000
    networks:
    - app-a-network

networks:
  app-a-network:
```

docker-compose-app-b.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: go/
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8012:8012
    volumes:
    - ../src/app:/go/src/app
    working_dir: /go/src/app
    container_name: app-b
    command: sleep 72000
    networks:
    - app-b-network

networks:
  app-b-network:
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to do this?
- If the first question is possible, Please suggest me :)

Comment: It is possible to use curl, error itself suggests that curl was successful to attempt connecting but the port was close. One thing though you can not use localhost to try to curl different container.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. It'll help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` on docker containers. The reason why your curl command didn't work is probably that you did not publish your docker container's port. For example, try:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 tomcat
```

instead of

```
docker run -d tomcat
```

This will forward the port 8080 of your machine to the port 8080 of your container.

If you have a shell to your container, you can use the service name or the container's name to curl a container on your Docker network, provided your target exists with the same network.

Comment: I already done with docker-compose below is result when I ran docker ps app_a port 0.0.0.0:80 network a, app_b 0.0.0.0:8080 network b

Comment: @ALTELMA: Can you edit your question to include your docker-compose file and the result of `docker ps` command?

Comment: I already updated my question and share some docker-compose.yaml. Anyway, I think it might be impossible . . .

Comment: @ALTELMA: You are trying to curl "App A" at port 8012. But, from what I see, App A is running on port 8011. It's "App B" that's running on port 8012.

Comment: Yep I try to curl from App A port 8011 to App B port 8012. So is it possible?

Comment: @ALTELMA: In this case, you should not use `localhost`. This will curl the container of "App A" instead of "App B". You should use the IP address of the host machine. If you're using Docker 18.03 or above, you can curl `host.docker.internal` which also points to the host machine of the container. REMEMBER, I'm assuming that you run both the containers on the same host.